# Let's Encrypt failing to request certificate on Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, python, certificate

I'm trying to get let's Encrypt to work on Ubuntu 16.04 server -> LAMP -> Webmin -> Virtualmin
However i get an error when requesting a certificate.
I used these commands to install:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install git bc
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --help
```

**Filled in this path inside**
*Webmin -> Webmin Configuration -> Module Config link or button on the top left corner ->  Full path to Let’s Encrypt client*
**/opt/letsencrypt/**

Error message:

```
Parsing account key...
Parsing CSR...
Registering account...
Already registered!
Verifying domain1234.com...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/webmin/webmin/acme_tiny.py", line 202, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/share/webmin/webmin/acme_tiny.py", line 198, in main
    signed_crt = get_crt(args.account_key, args.csr, args.acme_dir, log=LOGGER, CA=args.ca)
  File "/usr/share/webmin/webmin/acme_tiny.py", line 122, in get_crt
    resp = urlopen(wellknown_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1201, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: Isn't that a directory that you're pointing to in *"Full path to Let’s Encrypt client /opt/letsencrypt/"*? (Rather than the full path to the executable.)

Comment: I missed this part in the path 'certbot-auto'  doh. /opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto i azume this is the correct path. Off to the next errors :)

Answer (score 1):

The full path includes the filename for example: /x/y/filename.pls
In my case with Let's Encrypt the full path is: /opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto